# two results about irreducible polynomials over $F_2$

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

**Theorem 1**  For any  given $n(n\geqslant2)$ , there exist a $m$, such that $x^n+x^m+1$ is irreducible over binary field.

**Theorem 2**  For any  given $n(n\geqslant4)$ , there exist a $n_1,n_2,n_3$, such that $x^n+x^{n_1}+x^{n_2}+x^{n_3}+1$ is irreducible over binary field.

To some $n$(sucn as $n=8$) **Theorem 1** doesn't  hold any more,  but to  **Theorem 2** it seems that it holds always  if $n\geqslant4$. Now i want to prove this theoretically, i have considered it for a very long time. Who can help me! please....

Comment: Just one remark. A random polynomial of degree $n$ over the field of two elements is irreducible with probability $1/n$ (subtract a correction term negligible for larger $n$). That suggests that Theorem 1 is touch and go, and that Theorem 2 is likely to be true (or at least have only very few exceptions). This is somewhat in line with what Gerry Myerson found. I also think that these questions are difficult.

Answer (score 4):

There is a lot of work on irreducible trinomials. [This paper](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/98/HPL-98-135.pdf) says, among other things, that irreducible trinomials over the field of two elements don't exist if $n$ is a multiple of $8$. [This paper](http://cosec.bit.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/user_upload/publications/pubs/gat03a.pdf) mostly works over the field of three elements, but it gives references to papers that deal with the two-element field. Another paper with some relevant results and references is [this one](http://web.science.mq.edu.au/~doche/redundant.pdf).

Comment: Basically, type "irreducible trinomial" into the web and get many papers.

Comment: it seems that what you say is not helpful to prove $Theorem 2$

Comment: What I say is not helpful, but where I point, is. If you look at those papers and the other ones that come up in a search for irreducible trinomial, you will find that some of them go on to look for "pentanomials". I got the impression that it's an unsolved problem, but I didn't read anything too closely --- that's your job!